# S value range after cvtColor() conversion to HSV with float32

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I converted my numpy array from 8 to 32 bits, resulting Hue values will range in [0,360]. from [OpenCV docs-Color conversions](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hsv), for 32-bit images: H, S, and V are left as is, after conversion.

However the Value channel range is still in [0,255], and the Saturation range changes to [0,1] while the range was [0,255] with 8 bits array. Could anyone help me to understand why does the conversion to float32 change the range of the Saturation channel while no change for Value channel range?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

greenRGB = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])
greenRGB = np.float32(greenRGB)

greenHSV = cv.cvtColor(greenRGB,cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
print(greenHSV, greenHSV.dtype)
```

returns:

```
[[[120.   1. 255.]]] float32
```

Comment: The problem is that you didn't convert to floating point correctly. The range of RGB components in a floating point image should be 0.0-1.0. So full intensity green is `[0.0,1.0,0.0]`, not `[0.0,255.0,0.0]`. When you use that, the output of the colour conversion fits the description in the documentation.